# Exact solution to nonlinear differential equation sought

Tags: differential-equations, tag-removed

I am looking for an exact solution to equation:
$w''=aw^{-1/3}+b[f(y)]w^{-5/3}$, where $w=w(y), f(y)$ - arbitrary function (in this case $y^n$ with arbitrary $n$); $a,b$ - constants.

Of course I can solve it using numerical methods for certain initial conditions, but I was looking for a exact solution in form of some simple, commonly known functions.
Anyone has an idea how to solve/simplify it or where to look for help?

Thanks,
Lor

Comment: You may want to give some motivation for why you need this solution.

Comment: (1) Are you sure that a numerical solution will not actually be more precise than a solution in terms of simple, common functions? Is your goal precision or something else? (2) This question may be better suited to Math.SE.

Comment: It is very unlikely that an "exact solution", whatever you mean by this, exists, especially when $f$ is an "arbitrary function".

Comment: The place to look for help is Kamke, Differentialgleichungen. But as I said it is very unlikely that there is a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

The case $n=2$, that is $f(y):=y^2$ allows some particular solutions. If $$
b=-a^2/3$$  then any solution of 
$$w' =ayw^{-1/3}$$
also solves
$$w''=aw^{-1/3}+by^2w^{-5/3}\ .$$
And if 
$$b=-3a^2/25$$
then any solution of
$$w' =\frac{3}{5}a\ yw^{-1/3} +y^{-1}w$$
also solves 
$$w''=aw^{-1/3}+by^2w^{-5/3}\ .$$
The above first order equations for $w$ are easily solved: the former by separation of variables, the latter putting $w:=yu$ reduces to 
$$u' =\frac{3}{5}a\ y^{-1/3}u^{-1/3}, $$
solved again by separation of variables.

I would be curious to know if the above second order ODE admits similar reductions for all pairs $(a,b)$.

Comment: Take $w(y) = v(y)^3$.  Maple says that the second-order equation "has linear symmetries", although I'm not sure how to find the transformation that linearizes it.  It appears to try to solve the equation by transforming it to a rather complicated first-order Abel equation and gets stuck there, although for some parameter values this works.  For example, with $a = 1, b = -3$ a rather complicated solution is found.